# Bubble Sort C# windows form

Tags: c#, winforms, sorting, bubble-sort

I am making a bubble sort for class and I am unsure of syntax. I have most of the coding working just missing a random 10-100 number syntax to get to sort and the code to get it to sort can anyone point me in the right direction.

```
public partial class BubbleSort : Form
{
    public BubbleSort()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (txtNumber.Text != "")
        {
            lstSort.Items.Add(txtNumber.Text);
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a number to add.");
        }

        txtNumber.Clear();

    }

    private void btnExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Application.Exit();
    }

    private void btnClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtNumber.Clear();
        lstSort.Items.Clear();
    }

    private void Sort_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void btnView_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: "I am making sorting. I have most of the coding working just missing a"...sorting :D

Comment: To generate random numbers use the Random class. To sort the random numbers, implement the bubble sort algorithm (see Wikipedia)

Comment: Use `Random r = new Random(); int newInt = r.Next(minValue, maxValue); ` to generate an int value from minValue to maxValue. For bubble sort algorithm, please google.

Answer (score 0):

i just made a simple example with an array, it´s really simple, hope it helps

```
int[] A = { 5, 3, 1, 4, 2 };
            for (int i = 4 ; i > 0; i--)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j< i ; j++)
                {
                    if (A[j] > A[j + 1])
                    {
                        int tmp = A[j + 1];
                        A[j + 1] = A[j];
                        A[j] = tmp;
                    }
                }               
                Console.WriteLine(); 
            }
```

also to make the random number:

```
Random rand = new Random(); 
int newInt = rand.Next(minValue, maxValue);
```

i called it rand, you can name it how ever you want

Comment: Getting an error in my btnView now            private void btnView_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int[] array = new int[10] { 13, 2, 5, 8, 23, 90, 41, 4, 77, 61 };
            lstSort.Items.Add(new int);
        }

Comment: here =>  if (txtNumber.Text != "")
        {
            lstSort.Items.Add(txtNumber.Text);
        }
        else

Comment: you may wanna put a space between the two ""